# How can I configure BaseX for use in VS Code

Tags: xml, cmd, xquery, visual-studio-code, basex

#### What's the problem

I am trying to get XQuery to work in VS Code using BaseX, but every time I try to execute a query using XML Tools, it fails because its execution in the command is returning an error code.

#### How do I know that is the problem?

On the [repository for the extension](https://github.com/DotJoshJohnson/vscode-xml/wiki/xquery-script-execution) it says:

> The output of the execution engine is captured via the stdout for your
> operating system. If the process exits with any code other than 0, any
> content written to stdout is shown as an error message. If the content
> from stdout contains a line number, the error prompt will contain a
> button to take you to the line in question.

The result that I receive when I run my query is the *exact* query result written as an error, which is exactly what you'd expect given the quote above.

#### How am I configuring the settings.json

On the aforementioned [repository](https://github.com/DotJoshJohnson/vscode-xml/wiki/xquery-script-execution), the `settings.json` is written as follows:

```
{
    "xmlTools.xqueryExecutionEngine": "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Altova\\AltovaXML2008\\AltovaXML.exe",
    "xmlTools.xqueryExecutionArguments": [
        "-xquery", "$(script)",
        "-in", "$(input)"
        "-out", "$(input).output.xml"
    ]
}
```

But, I am using BaseX, so I tried to create the equivalent of the above using it:

```
"xmlTools.xqueryExecutionEngine": "basex.bat",
"xmlTools.xqueryExecutionArguments": [
    "$(script)",
    "-i", "$(input)",
    "-o", "output.xml"
],
```

From the [basex docs](https://docs.basex.org/wiki/Command-Line_Options), this looks like the right execution idea.

Note:

1. If output.xml doesn't already exist, Windows sends an error code 9009. To get around that, I just use a predefined file but if there's a way to avoid this problem and just create the file without an error, I'd love to know how.
2. Writing the following

*Alternate settings.json*

```
"xmlTools.xqueryExecutionArguments": [
    "-o", "output.xml",
    "$(script)",
],
```

does not work, although that's the way I have to write it in the cmd (I have also tried this while including the input file, but as I don't use it in my particular case, I tried both ways).

#### What Works

In the `cmd`, writing

```
basex -o output.xml data.xq
```

Works, and if `output.xml` exists, then

```
echo %ErrorLevel%
```

returns `0`.

I am a bit confused on how `settings.json` is translated to the cmd, so I'm not sure how to recreate the problem encountered in VS Code in my cmd. If there is a way to ignore exit codes (and prevent halting the execution of my command), that would resolve my problem. Even better would be to find the correct way to write to `settings.json` that allows me to run my XQueries from VS Code.

#### Test data

For testing's sake, here are the files I use

`data.xsd`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xs:complexType name="personType">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="fname" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="minit" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="lname" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType> 
<xs:complexType name="peopleType">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="person" type="personType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:element name="peopleDB" type="peopleType"></xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

`data.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<peopleDB xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="data.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <person>
        <fname>John</fname>
        <minit>A</minit>
        <lname>Roger</lname>
    </person>
    <person>
        <fname>Fred</fname>
        <minit>X</minit>
        <lname>Gerald</lname>
    </person>
</peopleDB>
```

`data.xq`

```
<personDB>
{
let $d:=doc("data.xml") for $p in 
$d/peopleDB/person
return $p
}
</personDB>
```

Comment: Maybe you can have a look at this: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=deltaxml.xslt-xpath  And maybe ask Phil Fearon for guidance? And also contact Christian Gruen?

Answer (score 2):

The **XML Tools** extension for VSCode is not being maintained currently. There are however a few extensions for general XML programming tasks that I would recommend (I maintain the latter two):

- [Red Hat XML Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=redhat.vscode-xml)
- [DeltaXML's XSLT/XPath Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=deltaxml.xslt-xpath)
- [DeltaXML's XPath Notebook](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=deltaxml.xpath-notebook)

While none of these extensions yet have direct support for executing XQuery with BaseX, VS Code has built-in support for [Tasks](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks) that can execute shell commands.

You could therefore setup a user task (workspace-level tasks are also supported):

1. From the Command Palette (Ctrl-Shift-P), invoke the `Open User Tasks` command
2. From the 'Select a task template' options, select `Others`
3. A `tasks.json` file will be created, edit this file to be something like:

```json
       {
         "version": "2.0.0",
         "tasks": [
           {
             "label": "Run BaseX XQuery",
             "type": "shell",
             "command": "\"path\\to\\basex.bat\" \"-xquery\" ${file} \"-in\" \"${workspaceFolder}\\input.xml\" \"-out\" \"${workspaceFolder}\\output.xml\"
           }
         ]
       }
```

4. Save the file (Ctrl-S)

> Note: Care should be taken when escaping charaters like `\` and `*`
> in JSON

With these 4 steps completed, you can now run this task from VS Code (provided you have a workspace folder open) using the `Run Task` command.

You probably don't want to hard code the paths in the script like I've done in this example, but you can either use [Variable References](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference) to create something more flexible (perhaps even where you're prompted to select a file) or create a number of tasks with different `label` values and different paths.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to partially work. I know my answer comes pretty late; but maybe someone might still find this useful.

```json
"xmlTools.xqueryExecutionEngine": "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\BaseX\\bin\\basex.bat",
"xmlTools.xqueryExecutionArguments": [
    "-i", "$(input)",
    "-o", "$(input).output.xml",
    "$(script)"
]
```

**NOTE!** Your path to BaseX might differ from mine.

One thing I haven't figured out yet is how to have BaseX ignore XML-namespaces.